# Ubuntu 12.014 not connecting to LAN nor internet

Tags: 12.04, networking, interface

I have a Dell T-300 server running a Bios from 2008.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04.  I have loaded Apache, Samba and other programs.  I use Ubuntu as my file server.  Everything worked well for years.  Now I cannot access any files or programs from the LAN in my office.  The server is wired and other computers are wired.  The windows computers can see one another on the network, but the Ubuntu server is not seen by any other computer.

I setup a static IP when I first configured the computer.

When I look at the connection information, it states the following:

```
Wired Connection (default)
Interface                 Ethernet (eth1)
Driver                    tg3
Speed                     100Mb/s
Security                  None

IPv4
IP Address               10.22.66.10
Broadcast Address        10.22.66.255
Subnet mask              255.255.255.0
Default Rout             10.22.66.1


In my interface file is the following

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface 
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address  10.22.66.10
netmask  255.255.255.0
network 10.22.66.0
broadcast 10.22.66.255
gateway 10.22.66.1

dns-nameserver 10.22.66.1
dns-search local
```

Then I checked my -lshw and this is what I got

```
cory101@smart-monkey:~$ sudo lshw -class network 
  *-network                
       description: Ethernet interface 
       product: NetXtreme BCM5722 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express 
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
       logical name: eth0 
       version: 00 
       serial: 00:22:19:b5:a1:ce 
       capacity: 1Gbit/s 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 firmware=5722-v3.08, ASFIPMI v6.02 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair promiscuous=yes 
       resources: irq:305 memory:dfdf0000-dfdfffff 
  *-network 
       description: Ethernet interface 
       product: NetXtreme BCM5722 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express 
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
       logical name: eth1 
       version: 00 
       serial: 00:22:19:b5:a1:cf 
       size: 100Mbit/s 
       capacity: 1Gbit/s 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 duplex=full firmware=5722-v3.08, ASFIPMI v6.02 ip=10.22.66.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s 
       resources: irq:306 memory:dfef0000-dfefffff 
  *-network 
       description: Ethernet interface 
       physical id: 1 
       logical name: tap0 
       serial: da:c0:fd:55:80:06 
       size: 10Mbit/s 
       capabilities: ethernet physical 
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full firmware=N/A link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair promiscuous=yes speed=10Mbit/s
```

Notes:   I can `ping 8.8.8.8` successfully from the Dell Server, but I cannot `ping 10.22.66.1` from any windows computer in my LAN.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably this is not the case (because I suppose you could ping your ubuntu machine previously), but not all PC have to answer a ping request and that doesn't mean they are unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/network/interfaces` the correct syntax is `dns-nameservers` not `dns-nameserver` (note the `s` at the end). Your computer's `address` is `10.22.66.10`. You did not tell anything about the computer at `10.22.66.1`; I cannot guess why it does not answer pings.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  The 10.22.66.1 is the router.